# How to iterate over table and define class for tds of trs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iteration

I have a table like that:

```
<table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
....
<tr style="color: blue;" id="bankRecord377">      
  <td align="center" class="styleOdd"> <input type="checkbox" value="377" name="377"></td>
  <td align="center" class="styleOdd">377</td>
  <td align="center" class="styleOdd"></td>
  <td align="center" class="styleOdd">391</td>
</tr>
....
<tr style="color: blue;" id="bankRecord386">     
  <td align="center" class="styleEven"> <input type="checkbox" value="386" name="386"></td>
  <td align="center" class="styleEven">386</td>
  <td align="center" class="styleEven"></td>
  <td align="center" class="styleEven">396</td>
</tr>
...
<tr style="color: blue;" id="bankRecord322">     
  <td align="center" class="styleEven"> <input type="checkbox" value="322" name="386"></td>
  <td align="center" class="styleEven">322</td>
  <td align="center" class="styleEven"></td>
  <td align="center" class="styleEven">314</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

`class="styleOdd"` makes row gray background `class="styleEven"` makes row background blue. I iterate over that table with Struts2 and define classes but user can remove some of table rows when he sees that HTML file. If user remove one of the table row, e.x. :

```
<tr style="color: blue;" id="bankRecord386">
...
</tr>
```

Colors of background was gray, blue, gray. However it is gray, gray now(because user removed a tr which includes classEven tds).

All in all what I want is iterate over that table again and defining classes styleOdd, styleEven, styleOdd, styleEven... again.

How can I do it with JavaScript or JQuery?

**PS:** I want to it for my table(which has id=myTable)'s every tds of trs.

**EDIT:** I want it except for the first tr(and it's tds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) and [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/), but then you would iterate over the table rows twice. That might lead to unacceptable performance if your table has many rows.

I'd suggest using [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead:

```
$("#myTable tr").each(function(index, row) {
    var $cells = $("td", row);
    if (index & 1) {
        // Odd.
        $cells.removeClass("styleEven").addClass("styleOdd");
    } else {
        // Even.
        $cells.removeClass("styleOdd").addClass("styleEven");
    }
});
```

Comment: Performance is important for me. There may be many rows for my table. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: It works but just one thing more. How can I do it except for the first tr?

Comment: @kamaci, use `$("#myTable tr:gt(0)")` instead of `$("#myTable tr")`.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi It adds that classes to trs?

Comment: @kamaci, nope, it modifies the `<td>` elements (have a look at `$cells`). According to your question, that's where the classes are set.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, I changed   $cells.removeClass("styleEven").addClass("styleOdd"); and   $cells.removeClass("styleOdd").addClass("styleEven");
' places.(because being odd or even changed, we do it except for first so the second will be like first). Your solution works, thanks for your help.

Comment: This solution is ok, but I don't agree regarding the performance gains from using it. Do you have any proof regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selector to target odd rows. (there is also a [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector)

```
$('.td:odd').class('odd');
```

Trigger this when removing a row from the table to update classes.

There are also both [CSS Selector](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd) but not widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTable tr:odd td').toggleClass('styleOdd', true).toggleClass('styleEven', false);
$('#myTable tr:even td').toggleClass('styleOdd', false).toggleClass('styleEven', true);
```

I believe you could also do it automatically using CSS. Although it requires a fairly modern browser.

Updated to take into account the table ID